# package org.springframework.boot does not exist but not working for me

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

`I am trying to run the spring boot project in IntelliJ, I am facing issues when compiling the code. Detailed explanation below.`

`**bold**Error below **bold**`

`
javac StudentApplication.java

StudentApplication.java:6: error: package org.springframework.boot does not exist
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
^
StudentApplication.java:7: error: package org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure does not exist
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
^
StudentApplication.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
@SpringBootApplication
^
symbol: class SpringBootApplication
StudentApplication.java:14: error: cannot find symbol
SpringApplication.run(
^
symbol:   variable SpringApplication
location: class StudentApplication
4 errors
`

`Below is my StudentApplication.java`
'  I am getting the error in the  SpringApplication.run  '

```
//import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;


import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class StudentApplication {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    //ApplicationContext ctx =
        SpringApplication.run(
        StudentApplication.class, args);
    //System.out.println(ctx);
  }
}
```

`Below is my porm.xml` 
' With the  list   '
'   '

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>info.inet</groupId>
    <artifactId>coursestudent</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>coursestudent</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-rest-hal-browser</artifactId>
            <version> 3.3.6.RELEASE </version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I am unable to solve it. Even after adding the dependency in the porm.xml file. Anyone able to help me.
If required, I will push git to see the complete code. But please don't close it unnecessarily.`

Answer (score 1):

is your remote maven repo updated?
check

```
Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build tools -> Maven -> Repositories
```

Comment: I follow your instruction went through the  Maven Repositories. Yes, there is an error. Can you please give me the suggestion how to solve it

Comment: @krishna could you, pls, specify what's the problem there?

Comment: URL, Type, Updated ===> https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 , Remote, Error. But in the next line, everything is fine. ../.m2/repository, Local, 2021-01-17. I am sorry, I am unable to post the image

Comment: that's the root cause - you have to update the remote repo in order to use the latest spring boot version
if the update is failing, then check your connection to the remote repo (maybe a firewall is blocking it and etc.)

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException:java.io.IOException:Transfer for nexus-maven-repository-index.gz failed    ====> this is the error showing in the Maven Repositories. Can you please help me. I checked the internet connection. It is working fine.

Comment: there might be several reasons - most likely proxy settings...I don't think I can help you with this, the problem is most likely in your connection settings